# how to define a conditional xp:confirm?

Tags: xpages

I would like to use the xp:confirm action on a conditional status. Is there a way to compute the rendered property of this control?

I can compute the rendered property for the whole xp:eventHandler but not for an xp:actionGroup or xp:confirm.

Answer (score 0):

`xp:confirm` just adds client-side JavaScript to the button with:

```
if (!XSP.confirm("YOUR MESSAGE")){
    return false;
}
```

`XSP.confirm()` is an XPages wrapper for JavaScript confirm. The most flexible approach is to code the client-side JavaScript you want on the "Client" tab of the button, doing `return false` to prevent the button sending to the server as required.

Comment: My question was to achieve something different: sometimes I want the confirmation to appear. sometimes not. based upon conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very synthetic snippet which you however can fit to your needs, if I got you right and if it suits your use case. Not so elegant, but works.

```xml
<xp:panel id="mainPanel">
    <xp:button id="myBtn1"
        value="Ask confirmation on submit">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="mainPanel">
            <xp:this.action>
                #{javascript:
                    requestScope.put('myAnyVar', 'askConfirmation');
                }
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:button id="myBtn2"
        value="Dont ask confirmation on submit">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="mainPanel">
            <xp:this.action>
                #{javascript:
                    requestScope.put('myAnyVar','dontAskConfirmation');
                }
            </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <input type="hidden" id="doConfirm"
        value="#{requestScope.myAnyVar eq 'askConfirmation' ? '1' : '0'}">
    </input>
</xp:panel>
<br />
<br />
<xp:button id="btnSubmit"
    value="Submit">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.script>
            var confirmOption = dojo.byId('doConfirm').value;
            if (confirmOption === '1') {
                if (confirm('Proceed the submit?')) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        </xp:this.script>
        <xp:this.action>
            #{javascript:
                viewScope.smthSubmitted = new java.util.Date();
            }
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<br />
<br />
<xp:text value="Submit time: #{viewScope.smthSubmitted}" />
```

Comment: I've wrapped `<xp:confirm>` with conditional `<xp:actionGroup>`, and set the condition explicitly to `#{true}` or `#{false}`. Works well until first partial refresh. The XPages devs have forgotten to save and restore the `MethodBindingEx`'s parent on `saveState` and `restoreState` of `ActionGroup`. So, when the component tree gets loaded the first time, the `<xp:confirm>` gets its parent, reads parent's condition and decides, if it should render itself. But on refresh, the `<xp:confirm>`'s parent is not restored from the cache. So, no parent, no condition, and `<xp:confirm>` renders anyway.