# Value in xp:confirm is not being updated after partial refresh. Why?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

On an xpage I calculate the message for an xp:confirm control:

```
var arr = viewScope.get("attachmentsAll");
if(arr.length>0){
    return "";
}else{
    return arr.length + " Are you sure want to upload the file?";
}
```

the viewScope is being updated after the event has been executed. I check this via a xp:text and I notice that this assumption is true.

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr = viewScope.get("attachmentsAll")

return arr.length + " number?"}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>
```

The xp:confirm and xp:text reside in the same panel that is being partially updated after the event.

Can anyone explain me why the value for the viewScope variable is updated in the xp:text control and not in the xp:confirm control?

Comment: I'm not certain, but my gut feeling is order of events and place of action. xp:confirm isn't a server-side event, because you can't prompt for user response server-side. It's a server-side computation that then writes a response to the browser, to run next time the button triggers a partial refresh. Hopefully that will help you trace through what's set when. I thought I'd written a blog post about CSJS and server-side computations, but Google's not my friend on this search!

Answer (score 1):

The main idea of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004996/9165609) to your previous question was to put hidden `input` with computed value. What if you try to use `<xp:this.script>` instead of `xp:confirm`, and get the confirmation message from that hidden input the same way?

> Update

**The reason and the alternative solution that does not require to make any changes to existing xpage**

It came out that the back-end instance of `xp:confirm` evaluates the new message correctly. The new value is even being sent to the browser with the response to ajax request. But one of the functions of `XSP` client module is built so that it won't update the `querySubmit` listener function if there already exists one with the same name. So, we are stuck with the old confirmation function that contains the old message. There is a way to override this behavior without breaking any other features. I have tried this and it works for me.

Create a new `JavaScript` library (client-side). Add the code:

```js
if (!XSP._pushListenerTuned) {
    XSP.__pushListener = XSP._pushListener;
    XSP._pushListener = function x__pl(listeners, formId, clientId, scriptId, listener) {
        if (scriptId && scriptId.endsWith("_confirm")) {
            for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
                if (scriptId == listeners[i].scriptId) {
                    listeners.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            listeners.push(new this._SubmitListener(formId, listener, clientId, scriptId));
        } else {
            XSP.__pushListener(listeners, formId, clientId, scriptId, listener);
        }
    }
    XSP._pushListenerTuned = true;
}
```

Attach your new library as resource globally via theme or as page resource on required page. I guess placing the above code as `scriptBlock` on a required page should also work. Now, any `xp:confirm` component on any page (if you used theme resource), or on particular page and everywhere after visiting this page (if you used page resource or `scriptBlock`), will work as naturally expected.